# how to include the properties into the class? in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to put the properties into the class and inherit it to the each and single DIV ID. What's wrong with my code?

```
var startItem1X = randomRange(50,100);
var startItem1Y = randomRange(50,100);
var startItem2X = randomRange(50,100);
var startItem2Y = randomRange(50,100);
var startItem3X = randomRange(50,100);
var startItem3Y = randomRange(50,100);
var startmyClassX = randomRange(50,100);
var startmyClassY = randomRange(50,100);
var $(".myClass").
    css(randomRange(50,100);); // push everything to the Class.
```

How can I add these properties to be part of the class?

```
function runItem1() {
    /* Set a the starting position to be random by editing the css */
    $("#item1").css("left", startItem1X+"px");
    $("#item1").css("top", startItem1Y+"px");
    /* Cycle1 and Cycle2 variables allow infinite loop */ 
    (cycle1 = function() {
        var m = randomRange(50,100);
        var n = randomRange(75,150);
        item1.animate({left:'+='+n},2000);
        item1.animate({left:'+='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000)
        item1.animate({left:'-='+m, top:'+='+m}, 2000)
        item1.animate({left:'-='+n},2000);
        item1.animate({top:'-='+n},2000,cycle1)
    })();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the classes which are written in style sheets. If so, then, you need to do it using "Document Object Model Style Sheets". Have a look to -

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html